# Function takes another function as an argument and calls it twice inside its body

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
def apply_twice(func, arg):
   return func(func(arg))

def add_five(x):
   return x + 5

print(apply_twice(add_five, 10))
```

**I am not able to figure out how/why the output is 20!!**

For me, the flow for above code is like this:

```
def apply_twice(func, arg)    ==> def apply_twice(add_five, 10)

return func(func(arg))    ==> return add_five(add_five(10)) ==> return add_five(10 + 5) ==> return (20 + 5)
```

Comment: If you add 5 to 10 twice, you get 20 (10+5+5 = 20). Why do you expect to get something else?

Comment: How are you getting from `add_five(10 + 5)` to `return (20 + 5)`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh- Thank you for pointing out my mistake! Apart from that, is the above (my) flow correct way to understand the code?

Answer (score 0):

why not 20?

10+5=15
15+5=20

the last step should return 15+5